# DRV8889 SPI Commands

Tags: microcontroller, motor, spi, serial-bus

I've been having some issues diagnosing the relationship between writing to the registers through SPI commands and stepping the motors. That is, it seems like when I write SPI_STEP=1 (and STEP=1) to register CTRL3, pins AOUT1, AOUT2 and BOUT1, BOUT2 produce a PWM when I expected just a single-step.

So my question is, are the outputs to the DRV8889 chip pulses despite the inputs being a single write command (which I have as 0x50 for CTRL3 register)?

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, at first it seemed weird to me, but there is an internal regulator that regulates the current that goes through the motor windings.

A hint from the [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8889-q1.pdf) page 17

[image: Hint from datasheet]

Comment: Oooh okay I was suspicious about this part being the culprit... I’m not sure how to go about calculating how long the pulses are for and thus determining the duty cycle. Any ideas?

Comment: Oscilloscope is my best idea.